# My Flutter programs and Android Studio programs are not working anymore

Tags: flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code

I recently updated my Android Studio and Flutter (Visual Studio Code) and suddenly all the working programs I had written, both in Android Studio and VS code, are full of errors. I've tried uninstalling and re-installing both platforms, however, that didn't change anything. How can I resolve this?

There are even errors in the demo app in Flutter as I've shown below:

[image: flutter demo app]

Comment: Did you run flutter pub get after updating?

Comment: What IDE version you upgraded to?

Comment: Yes, I did run flutter pub get after updating and still encountered the same errors

Comment: I upgraded to Android Studio Dolphin